# C# How can I get the return value of a method and put it in a variable

Tags: c#

I am new to C# and I am trying to learn by solving issues . I have a method called `StatusController.Check()` that method will return an enum called EnumStatus and an integer called `VehicleIdentifier` .

That method works fine, I now call that method in a different class and want to know how can I get the return value of EnumStatus and VehicleIdentifier in the `HomeController.Main()` `ActionResult` so that I can put it into 2 separate variables .

```
namespace MyHome.Controllers 
{
    public class HomeController
    {
        public ActionResult Main()
        {
            var getStatus = new StatusController();
            getStatus.Check("V2Yq7"); 

            // How can I get the return value of the Check method
            // It will return an Enum of type string and an Integer called
            // VehicleIdentifier
            // I would like to put that values inside the variables below .

            var EnumStatus = "";
            var VehicleIdentifier = ;       
        }   
    }
}  


namespace BTree.Controllers
{
    public class StatusController : AllStatusController
    {
        [HttpPost]
        public Models.StatusCheck Check(string uniqueID)
        {
            var statusRepository = new Repository.StatusRepository<StatusModel>();
            var myModel = statusRepository.GetStatus(uniqueID);

            if (myModel.CurrentStatus == EnumStatus.Sold)
            {
                var VehicleRepository = new VehicleRepository();
                var getVehicle = VehicleRepository.GetVehicle(myModel.MakeID, myModel.IDType);
                return new Models.StatusCheck
                {
                    EnumStatus = EnumStatus.Sold,
                    VehicleIdentifier = getVehicle(Make, uniqueID)
                };
            }
            else
            {
                return new Models.StatusCheck { EnumStatus = myModel.EnumStatus };
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `StatusCheck result = getStatus.Check()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply assign the result to another variable and then reference that variable instance's properties:

```
var getStatus = new StatusController();
var statusResult = getStatus.Check("V2Yq7"); 

var EnumStatus = statusResult.EnumStatus;
var VehicleIdentifier = statusResult.VehicleIdentifier;
```

Answer (score 1):

try to create a class..

project >> Add Class

```
//set your class to public here
public class yourclassname
{
    public static string getStatus
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public static string vehicleIdentifier
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

And then just simply save the status to your class to hold the values...

```
yourclassname.getStatus = EnumStatus.Sold; //if it is sold
yourclassname.vehicleIdentifier = getVehicle(Make, uniqueID);
```

to get or use the values just simply call them

```
var status = yourclassname.getStatus;
var vehicleIdent = yourclassname.vehicleIdentifier;
```

Hopee it helps..